# How to delete text before a specific character - Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, string, pandas, substring, series

I have a column in a larger dataset that looks like:

```
Name
----
Mr. John Doe
Jack Daw
Prof. Charles Winchester
Jane Shaw
... etc.
```

(Names anonymized)

Basically, its a list of names that have prefixes mixed in. All prefixes end with a dot. So far, the prefixes have been limited to: Mr. Mrs. Ms. Dr. and Prof.

The output I would like is:

```
Name
----
John Doe
Jack Daw
Charles Winchester
Jane Shaw
... etc.
```

Ideally, I would like a solution that relies on the position of the dot instead of having to create multiple if conditions (or something equivalent). Below is what I have attempted and where it went wrong:

```
def mid(s, offset, amount):
    return s[offset:offset+amount]
print(mid(Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name'],Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name'].str.find('.'),len(Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name'])))

Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name']=mid(Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name'],Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name'].str.find('.'),len(Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name']))
```

The above returned the error "TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers"

I also tried:

```
print(Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name'][(Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name'].str.find('.')):])
```

Same error as above

A different approach:

```
Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name']=Sample_Raw_Emp_Data['Name'].str.rsplit('.', expand=True,n=1)[1]
```

The result looked like:

```
Name
----
John Doe
None
Charles Winchester
None
... etc.
```

Instances that used to have a prefix remained, while the rest became None. I am not sure how to retain both.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Name'].str.split('\.').str[-1].str.strip()
```

Output:

```
0              John Doe
1              Jack Daw
2    Charles Winchester
3             Jane Shaw
Name: Name, dtype: object
```